# Find -delete command return successfully if file doesn't exist

Tags: find

I have `autosys` job which deletes files older than X days with below command

```
find /home/myhome -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +31 -name "abc_*" -delete -print
```

above job is failing with `No such file or directory`

I suspect it is due to some other parallel job is deleting some of the files. is there any way to hide such error if file is not present (perhaps by passing some flag)

[EDIT] TLDR; The requirement is above command should exit with status 0 regardless of whether file is deleted or not.

Comment: `return successfully`, `hide such error` – What do you mean exactly? Suppress the message? Not let it affect exit status? Make `-print` work regardless? All these? Please [edit] and be specific.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have added short note

Comment: In my tests, if the file is removed in the meantime, not only `-delete` will affect the exit status but also `-mtime`. Are there any errors you *do* want to catch? If not, consider `find … || true`; it should *always* succeed.

Comment: Your [other question](https://superuser.com/q/1447375/432690) is similar. There you explicitly state that troublesome files don't match the pattern. Here you say nothing about whether they match the pattern or not. I'm not claiming the questions are duplicates, still if they stem from the same *actual* problem then maybe we should consider them together; or even try to find another approach (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)).