# find command is picking files of unrelated pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

I have a following `find` command which I trigger via `autosys` scheduler. The command is used to delete file older than `X` days.

```
find /home/my_home/document -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +31 -name "qwer_*" -delete -print
```

But above command fails is failing.
Weird part is, in logs I can see find is picking up the files which does not even match the `qwer_*` pattern

eg.

```
find: `/home/my_home/document/yumn.txt': No such file or directory
find: `/home/my_home/document/ztry.txt': No such file or directory
```

Am I missing anything in `find` command.

Comment: `find` evaluates the tests in the order in which they appear, so it tests type and modification date before it checks the name pattern. But this doesn't explain why it doesn't find them (bad link would have been an explanation, but I cannot generate the error). Another explanation is that you are somehow using  `/home/my_home/document/*` ( `find` also accepts files as starting points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1444195/432690) you said:

> I suspect it is due to some other parallel job is deleting some of the files.

This is exactly what happened in this case. Your `find` found out there's a file `yumn.txt`, then the file was deleted, then `find` tried to do something with the file and failed. The same scenario for `ztry.txt`.

Note it doesn't mean that if `yumn.txt` was not simultaneously deleted, then `find` would delete and print it. It only means `yumn.txt` unexpectedly disappeared before `find` was done testing it.

---

You may expect `-name "qwer_*"` to reject `yumn.txt` according to sole directory listing (from which `find` learns about the existence of the file in the first place), so the tool never needs to query about the file itself (later, when the file doesn't exist). My tests indicate this is not always the case.

In general `find` may or may not rearrange tests. This means `-name "qwer_*"` may be tested before or after `-mtime +31` etc. E.g. GNU `find` reorders expressions so that tests based only on the names of files are performed early. See `man 1 find`, `-O` and `-D` options. But in your case *maybe* what you typed first was tested first, so `yumn.txt` was meant to be tested against `-type f` and `-mtime +31`, and at least one of these tests required the file to exist at the moment the test was performed.

But even with sole `find . -name "qwer_*"` it's possible to encounter the problem. I tested like this:

```
while true; do touch yumn.txt; rm yumn.txt; done &
```

Then `ls yumn.txt` would find a file or not. You can repeat `ls yumn.txt` many times and sometimes you will find a file, sometimes not. This is expected.

In my Debian, when `yumn.txt` keeps being created and destroyed on a Btrfs filesystem, `find . -name "qwer_*"` doesn't complain about it; or at least it did not when I tested repeatedly more than 4k times.

On the other hand in my OpenWRT router `find . -name "qwer_*"` sometimes *does* complain, and the message is almost exactly like yours:

```
find: ./yumn.txt: No such file or directory
```

It's `find` from BusyBox and the filesystem is `overlayfs` (with `ext3` as the upperdir). The conclusion is: in some circumstances it's possible that a file being deleted by another process makes `find` complain (and return non-zero exit status!), even if `-name` could in theory reject the file in the first place.

---

Not a general solution, but in your specific case you can try this approach:

```
find /home/my_home/document/qwer_* -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +31 -delete -print
```

Now the shell performs pattern matching and runs `find` with only matching files as starting points. Because of `-maxdepth 0` `find` examines only the given files (relevant if at least one of them happens to be a directory). This way disappearing `yumn.txt` or such cannot affect `find`. Possible problems:

- If `qwer_*` files are deleted by other process(es) (like `yumn.txt` was), it may happen `find` complains and returns non-zero exit status.
- If there are too many `qwer_*` files then you will get `Argument list too long` (or similar).
- If there is no match at all, `find` will get literal `/home/my_home/document/qwer_*` starting point and complain about nonexisting file/directory.